# ¿Cómo extraer elementos de un array con el metodo filter segun un rango de fechas en Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un `array` **ordersArray** cuyos elementos que tiene son: **id_order, order_date**, etc..
La idea es obtener en el `array` **filterOrdersArray** todas las ordenes que cumplan con la condicion del rango de fechas elegidas. Es decir si el usuario elige como **fecha1: 01/01/20** y **fecha2: 10/10/20** filtrar esa condicion en **ordersArray** y que el resultado lo guarde en **filterOrdersArray**.
Hice esto pero no da resultado:

`component.ts`

```js
ordersArray: Order[] = []; // array de tipo Order
filterOrdersArray: Order[] = [];
date1: Date;
date2: Date;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.orderService.getOrdersByUserId(1)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.ordersArray = res;
    },
      err => console.error('No se pudo obtener las ordenes de compra   del usuario ' + err)  
    ); 
}

filterOrdersByDate(){
  console.log('date1: ' + this.date1);
  console.log('date2: ' + this.date2);
// haciendo el filtrado segun el rango de fechas
  this.filterOrdersArray.push(...this.ordersArray.filter(item => item.order_date >= this.date1 && item.order_date <= this.date2));
}
```

`component.html`

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Desde:</label>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>fecha 1</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="date1">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Hasta:</label>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>fecha 2</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" [(ngModel)]="date2">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field> 
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <button mat-raised-button color="dark" (click)="filterOrdersByDate()">Filtrar</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar esto:

```
  const products = [
  {
    productId: "13",
    date: "2015-10-01T00:00:00Z",
  },
  {
    productId: "14",
    date: "2015-08-06T00:00:00Z",
  },
  {
    productId: "15",
    date: "2015-09-01T00:00:00Z",
  }
];
 var startDate = new Date("2015-08-04");
var endDate = new Date("2015-08-12");

var filterByDate = products.filter(a => {
  var date = new Date(a.date);
  return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
});
console.log("filterByDate", filterByDate);
```